# What to do about the fact that PHP's escapeshellarg() function is broken on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, terminal

I have files with valid file names. If they weren't valid, they would not be possible to keep on my file system. Windows. NTFS.

For example:

```
E:\videos\Happy Fun Time!.mp4
```

If I do:

```
if (file_exists('E:\videos\Happy Fun Time!.mp4'))
```

Then PHP "sees" the file; it exists. Good.

However, if I try to actually use the file's path, for example by sending it in a command:

```
shell_exec('test.exe --input=' . escapeshellarg('E:\videos\Happy Fun Time!.mp4'));
```

... then the test.exe receives/is sent:

```
test.exe --input="E:\videos\Happy Fun Time .mp4"
```

It has turned the "!" into a space, thus making it no longer valid.

I know that they do this for security reasons, and that proper escaping on Windows is something of a nightmare. Nevertheless, it still remains a problem, since I cannot refer to any file containing a "!" and possibly also other valid characters.

When bringing this kind of thing up, I generally tend to get a "meh... we don't really feel like supporting your weird OS" response from developers. They act as if Windows is some kind of obscure Linux distro instead of the #1 desktop OS in the world. Even if you think it sucks, which I very much agree that it does, BTW, isn't a coding challenge "fun" in some way to smart programmers? It's rather frustrating when people act as if PHP and other software is cross-platform when in reality it's "Linux-first, and maybe some half-baked Window support if we have the time and feel like it". (But I'll stop there, fearing a "rant" marking.)

In the user comments in the PHP manual, there are various crazy solutions proposed, as is typical. I really don't feel comfortable using any of them, both for security reasons and also because it just feels weird to rely on some user-submitted comment from many years ago instead of the actual PHP function to perform this critical task of escaping/securing terminal arguments/paths.

How can it be that `file_exists` is able to safely check for its existence, even with the "!"? Does `file_exist` have some internal code which safely and properly checks all valid file names, whereas `escapeshellarg()` for some reason lacks this? Or does `file_exist` "ask the OS" or "ask the file system" in some built-in way which entirely bypasses having to handle the escaping of the file path string?

I don't know what to do now. Some guy has linked to ReactOS source code, but that's not PHP, and if that's such a great solution, why hasn't that been incorporated into PHP itself? I don't understand why so many PHP functions are never updated/enhanced, or new improved ones added, rather than having every individual "PHPhant" (that's what I call myself and other PHP users) try to cobble together their own solution to such important and common tasks?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what the `!` does in windows shell but if you know it is safe you could swap it with a placeholder prior to the call, escape, the swap the placeholder back. I haven't been able to find the `file_exists` definition in PHP source yet. Also perhaps one of the solutions at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php#123718 solves this?

Comment: You probably need `^!` caret escaping if you keep using cmd.exe rather than Powershell with its more consistent command-line tail "parsing".

Comment: @mario I don't use cmd.exe. PHP does. And Windows. Furthermore, PowerShell has numerous weird issues which I've experienced first-hand when trying to force PHP and myself to use it. And now that Windows Terminal is becoming a thing, PowersHell is a thing of the past anyway, I assume. But again, I'm not using cmd.exe. It's what's... used.

Comment: @user3783243 I've begun using this now, but it feels extremely weird to be using third-party code instead of PHP's own function: https://github.com/johnstevenson/winbox-args